# Redirect socket communications through intermediate processes

Tags: c, linux, sockets, nftables

I have the following network:

```
~~~~~~~ MACHINE A ~~~~~~~                   ~~~~~~~~ MACHINE B ~~~~~~~~

+--------+                                                   +--------+
| client |----(a)                               (b)----------| server |
+--------+     |                                 |   [port Z]+--------+
               |                                 |
               |                                 |
               |[port X]                         |
        +---------------+                   +---------------+
        | interceptor A |-------------------| interceptor B |
        +---------------+           [port Y]+---------------+
```

For context:

- All machines are Raspberry Pi's running Raspberry Pi OS, Linux kernel 5.15.
- The solution should be language agnostic, if possible. However, I am using C.
- IP addresses are statically assigned.
- There are more than two machines on the network that need to communicate in this fashion.
- All processes need to run in user space.

On Machine A, process `client` needs to communicate with process `server` (listening on port Z) on Machine B on the same local network. This would normally occur via a simple TCP socket. However, I want to intercept the bytes sent from `client` to `server` (and vice versa, since TCP is bidirectional) and do some "magic" with processes `interceptor A` and `interceptor B` before "forwarding" the data to `server`. Importantly, the actual TCP connection between the machines must be independently handled by client `interceptor A` and server `interceptor B` (listening on port Y). However, `client` and `server` need to think they're communicating with each other directly.

My initial solution is the following:

1. Use nftables at point `(a)` to modify destination IP/port so that packets are redirected to `interceptor A` (listening on port X) instead of `server`. So, when `client` attempts to connect to `server` on port B, it actually connects to `interceptor A` (acting as server) on port X.
2. `interceptor A` then connects to `interceptor B`. It does any processing before "forwarding" the bytes from `client`.
3. `interceptor B` connects to `server`. However, at point `(b)`, also use nftables to transform source IP/port to that of `client` instead of `interceptor B`. So `server` thinks it just accepted a connection with `client`.

**TL;DR:**
I need to redirect an outgoing socket connection to localhost, do some processing with the bytes and retransmit those bytes over a new connection to endpoint. Endpoints should not know there are intermediate processes managing the real inter-machine connection.

**Questions:**

1. Is setting NAT rules in nftables a proper solution? It seems that the normal usage of NAT (transforming private IP to global IP) does the operations in the opposite order, but it seems that it would work.
2. More importantly, how can `interceptor A`, as an application-layer process, know which IP address `client` was originally trying to communicate with? This is necessary so it can create a connection to `interceptor B` on the correct machine.

This project is in the planning phase, so I don't have a minimum working example. I'm willing to edit the question to add one, but I think the minimum working example is really just what I'm trying to achieve.